# Actionbar Sherlock: Setting and hiding title bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm new to ActionBarSherlock, and am having two problems:

First, I just want to be able to set the title of the action bar, but it doesn't work when I call it like this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
actionBar.setTitle("test title");
```

Where the corresponding xml object looks like this:

```
<com.myapp.prototype.ActionBar
    android:id="@+id/actionBar2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

(This is modeled after the github example: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/blob/master/actionbarexample/src/com/markupartist/android/actionbar/example/HomeActivity.java).  In other places on the web, I see reference to getSupportActionBar(), but I'm not clear how or where to call this.

Second, in another place I just want to be able to hide the Activity's title bar altogether.  I'm trying to do this by calling:

```
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

but I can't even get this to compile.  The error I'm getting is:

```
"The method setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type
 ActionBar."
```

In both cases, I guess the Actionbar Sherlock overrides are involved in the problem.  Any suggestions how to make this work?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up two different ActionBar implementations. ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library provided by Google. The methods used with ActionBarSherlock are almost identical to the native ActionBar found in Android 3.0+ http://actionbarsherlock.com/

The Github link provided (and code you are using) is a custom implementation of an actionbar https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar.

I would advise you use ActionBar sherlock and follow the usage guide here http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

There is also an ActionBarSherlock getting started video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4GJ6yY1lNNY

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow, I didn't catch that the johannilsson implementation was not based on ABS.  I've gone back to the ABS demo code, and it's working out.  Cheers.

Answer (score 40):

#### Setting the `ActionBar` title

```
setTitle("Title")
```

#### Hiding and showing the `ActionBar`

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get the desired effect now.

Comment: Isn't there the possibility to hide the titlebar without hiding the whole ActionBar? This doesn't appear to be a sufficient solution for the requested action.

Comment: If you just want to hide the title, call `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to hide title-bar only, not complete actionbar as I have split action items in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You need to import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window so that it secretly uses the long version of this method.